# How could i make a discord slash command bot that sends http requests and returns info as an embed

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, discord.py

eg.

user sends a command **/findsomething [something: ]** where **"something"** is compulsory

the value in the **"something"** variable is then stored in a variable and used in the link of a http request

the response is iterated in an embed and the embed is sent back to the user who sent the request with all info in place

how can i achieve this? what modules and how can i approach the issue?

ive looked on the internet and cannot find anything which helps with this problem

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) module.

Assuming you already created the basic bot and the command function, you'll first need to `defer` the interaction with [Interaction.response.defer](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.defer), use the `aiohttp` module to make the request, and then respond to the user using [Interaction.followup.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.followup).

Here's how you can make the command:

```py
from discord import app_commands
import aiohttp

tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name="yourcommandname")
async def the_command(interaction, something):
    await interaction.response.defer()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://yourwebsite.com/" + something) as response: # change that to how your website works
            html = await response.text()
    
    await interaction.followup.send(content=discord.Embed(description=html))
```

Comment: Yoooo thank you so much it works

ive been stuck on this for the past few hrs tysm